# Construct operator such that division of expectation values is equal to expectation value of the operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Is is possible to construct an operator $\hat{C}$ out of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ such that:
$$\frac{\langle \psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\hat{B}|\psi\rangle} = \langle \psi|\hat{C}|\psi\rangle,$$
for any state $|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: Suggestion to post (v3): Multiply both sides of eq. with denominator to avoid potential issue with division by zero.

Comment: $\hat A = \hat C = 0$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The *r.h.s.* is a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), while the *l.h.s.* is not. For example, under $\psi\to\lambda\psi$ the *r.h.s.* scales as $\lambda^2$ while the *l.h.s.* stays the same.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that this equation holds for particular $|\psi \rangle$. Putting $N |\psi \rangle$ would result in:

$$
\frac{\langle \psi| \hat{A} |\psi \rangle}{\langle \psi| \hat{B} |\psi \rangle} = |N|^2 \langle \psi| \hat{C} |\psi \rangle
$$

Which of course can hold only for $|N|^2 = 1$.